# notepad ++ Help need to split groups of 4,6,8 digits to groups of 2

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

I have some data and would like to split the groups of 4,6 and 8 digits into groups of 2

```
3 16 53 7282 192331 68 83 9 29364255 00001
4 10 57 7188 6 3943 6574 1228 4558 79 00002
2 415266 80 142433 7887 26 445669 89 00003 
1 223440 85 5 27 596270 13 3749 6375 00004 
15 32 607381 17 465061 84 7 2035 5167 00005
```

output needed

```
3 16 53 72 82 19 23 31 68 83 9 29 36 42 55 00001
4 10 57 71 88 6 39 43 65 74 12 28 45 58 79 00002
2 41 52 66 80 14 24 33 78 87 26 44 56 69 89 00003
1 22 34 40 85 5 27 59 62 70 13 37 49 63 75 00004
15 32 60 73 81 17 46 50 61 84 7 20 35 51 67 00005
```

I'm not worried of this effect the 00001, 00002 as I can fix this after export to excel

screen shot of data:

[image]

Comment: - [FAQ Desk: Where to find REGEX documentation ? | Notepad++ Community](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15765/faq-desk-where-to-find-regex-documentation)
 - [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\b(\d\d)(\d\d)?(\d\d)?\b`
- Replace with: `$1(?2 $2)(?3 $3)`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b              # word boundary, make sure we haven't a digit before
(\d\d)          # group 1, 2 digits
(\d\d)?         # group 2, 2 digits, optional
(\d\d)?         # group 3, 2 digits, optional
\b              # word boundary, make sure we haven't a digit after
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1              # content of group 1, the first 2 digits
(?2 $2)         # if group 2 exists, insert a space and content of group 2
(?3 $3)         # if group 3 exists, insert a space and content of group 3
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Its not quite what I was looking for.

I managed to do it this way

I added a 0 to all single digits

\b(\d)\b
0$1  (space at end)

then removed all spaces and then split everything into group of 2 digits

(..)
\1 (space at end)

which worked apart from the ticket number was 00 00 1 instead of 00001

Comment: This is not what you have asked in the question. You should ask a new question with exact input sample lines and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. Its not quite what I was looking for.

I managed to do it this way

I added a 0 to all single digits

\b(\d)\b
0$1  (space at end)

then removed all spaces and then grouped into 2

(..)
\1 (space at end)

which worked apart from the ticket number was 00 00 1 instead of 00001

which I fix when I imported into excel

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yoo9r.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).